# One If Statement, different default result

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I'm pretty new to powerapps but learning as I go. Is there a way to write the following if statements as one statement? (that way it will only create one item on my sharepoint list, instead of seperate items for each if statement). I am struggling to do so as each If statement has a different default result.

```
If(
    IsEmpty(MondayCombo.SelectedItems),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Monday: DataCardValue82.Text}
    ),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Monday: Concat(
                MondayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);
If(
    IsEmpty(TuesdayCombo.SelectedItems),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Tuesday: DataCardValue83.Text}
    ),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Tuesday: Concat(
                TuesdayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);
If(
    IsEmpty(WednesdayCombo.SelectedItems),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Wednesday: DataCardValue84.Text}
    ),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Wednesday: Concat(
                WednesdayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);
If(
    IsEmpty(ThursdayCombo.SelectedItems),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Thursday: DataCardValue85.Text}
    ),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Thursday: Concat(
                ThursdayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately PowerApps don't have the `return` or `exit` command yet to break the code execution.

You have to come up with a workaround to verify the code execution & bypass all the other unwanted code execution. For example, we can have a bool variable to set & validate in next loop.

```
UpdateContext({RecordCreated:false});
If(
    IsEmpty(MondayCombo.SelectedItems),
    UpdateContext({RecordCreated:true});
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Monday: DataCardValue82.Text}
    ),
    UpdateContext({RecordCreated:true});
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Monday: Concat(
                MondayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);
If(RecordCreated = false,
If(
    IsEmpty(TuesdayCombo.SelectedItems),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {Tuesday: DataCardValue83.Text}
    ),
    Patch(
        ChangeOfService,
        Defaults(ChangeOfService),
        {
            Tuesday: Concat(
                TuesdayCombo.SelectedItems,
                Value,
                ", "
            )
        }
    )
);)
```

Please up-vote [this idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Exit-formula-on-condition/idi-p/110466)